# How to prevent user to enter spaces only at first place in an input feild and can add spaces after some characters in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Prevent the user from entering blank spaces in the first position.

`$event.preventDefault()` with this I can't even enter space after firstname.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Enter Your Name" formControlName="name" value="{{user_name}}" maxlength="40" >
```

There should not be any space showing in the input field.

Comment: Search for mask, otherwise just a simple validator or trim the result

Comment: @maxime1992, the thing is that I don't want the user to even enter blank spaces. i.e. if they press spacebar at first position then nothing happens.

Comment: I think it would be better if you let users to type whatever they want, and you trim the first spaces programatically

Comment: Agree with adrita but in that case if that's what you want search for `mask` ;)

Comment: Like that for ex https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you, but the problem is sorted now.

Comment: Just used this on the key down event -:
   keyDownHandler(event) {
    if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if (event.keyCode === 32) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }